# integration of $\ln \ln x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

I would like to compute the following integral :

$$\int_{2}^{\frac{\ln a}{\ln \ln a}} \ln \ln x \, \mathrm{d}x$$

where $a$ is a positive constant.

Is this possible ?

Comment: You can do partial integration with $u=1$ and $v = \ln\ln x$. Differentiate $v$

Comment: The integral of $\ln\ln x$ is $x\ln\ln x - \mathrm{li}(x)$, where $\mathrm{li}$ is the [logarithmic integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function)

Comment: Yes. That's the result of the partial integration.

Answer (score 2):

The integral of interest cannot be evaluated in terms of elementary funcitons.  Rather, the integral embeds the special function, [The Logarithmic Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Integral_representation).

To see this, we integrate by parts with $u=\log(\log(x))$ and $v=x$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\int \log(\log(x))\,dx&=x\log(\log(x))-\int \frac{1}{\log(x)}\,dx\\\\
&=x\log(\log(x))-\text{li}(x)+C
\end{align}$$

where $\text{li}(x)$ is given by

$$\text{li}(x)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{\log(t)}\,dt$$

Comment: Thanks Dr MV , Can we evaluate the result asymptotically ? by applying your formula from 2 to $\ln a / \ln \ln a$ ? Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  - Mark

Comment: Tell me what you mean by "evaluate the result asymptotically?"

Comment: For example, are we able to say that the result is in $O(something)$ ? ( Big O notation).

Comment: At $\infty$, you have $\operatorname{li}(x) = \frac{x}{\ln x} + O\left( \frac{x}{\ln^2 x} \right)$. Is it what you mean? (see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Asymptotic_expansion).)

Comment: Asymptotically, as $a\to+\infty$? Or $a\to$ something else?

Comment: Is $a$ arbitrarily "large?"  Or is $a$ arbitrarily close to $1$

Comment: $a$ is arbitrary large.

Comment: For $a$ large, we can use the result posted in the comment posted herein by @ClementC.

Comment: Thank you very much  (Clement C. also)

Comment: You're welcome... did not do much. :)

Comment: @ClementC. I disagree.  I think your comment added quite a lot here.  - Mark

Comment: one should mention that the asymptotic expansion is only accurate for really big values of x. taking only the first term we have still an error of approx 11% for $x\approx 10^5$

Comment: @tired Yes.  The term $\log(\log(\log(\log(a))))$ grows pretty, pretty, pretty, .... pretty slowly.  Hope you don't mind the obscure "Curb Your Enthusiasm" reference.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?